# Android Kotlin firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have followed the advice of other SO solution:
1. Make my class Serializeable
2. Have a default constructor for Firebase
3. Update my proguard rules (Not sure about this one)

And still I get the above error, any ideas?

```
package org.sherman.android.stub_firebase.Models

import java.io.Serializable

/**
 * Created by fyi2 on 2/21/18.
 */
class User(displayName:String, email:String, photoUrl:String, userId:String) : Serializable {
    constructor(): this("","","","")



}
```

New Class Definition:

```
class User :Serializable {
    private var displayName:String=""
    private var email:String=""
    private  var photoUrl:String=""
    private var userId:String=""

    constructor() {}

    constructor(displayName: String, email: String, photoUrl: String, userId: String) {
        this.displayName = displayName
        this.email = email
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl
        this.userId = userId
    }

}
```

Proguard Rule:

```
-keepclassmembers class org.sherman.android.stub_firebase.Models.** { *; }
```

Code where it is called:

```
fun registerUserToFirebase(email:String, password:String){
    mAuth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)?.addOnCompleteListener(this){ task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful){
            mProgressDialog?.dismiss()
            var currentUserFB = task.getResult().user as FirebaseUser
            var user = User("Bobby", currentUserFB!!.email!!, "", currentUserFB!!.uid)
            mUsersDB!!.child(currentUserFB.uid).setValue(user)
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        } else {
            Helper.showAlertDialog("Error!",task.exception?.message!!,this)

        }
    }
}
```

ERROR Log snippet:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class org.sherman.android.stub_firebase.Models.User
                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.<init>(Unknown Source:799)
                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzf(Unknown Source:12)
                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:259)
                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbw(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                       at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                       at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source:7)
                                                                                       at org.sherman.android.stub_firebase.Activities.RegisterActivity$registerUserToFirebase$1.onComplete(RegisterActivity.kt:59)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, even in Kotlin it seems the variables had to be explicitly Public.

```
import java.io.Serializable

/**
 * Created by fyi2 on 2/21/18.
 */
class User :Serializable {
    public var displayName:String=""
    public var email:String=""
    public  var photoUrl:String=""
    public var userId:String=""

    constructor() {}

    constructor(displayName: String, email: String, photoUrl: String, userId: String) {
        this.displayName = displayName
        this.email = email
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl
        this.userId = userId
    }

}
```

Once that was modified, the rest worked as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the issue on release apk then
Do like this in your proguard file

```
    -keepattributes Signature
```

```
    -keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
      *;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use a data class, it already comes with an empty constructor ect.

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User(
    var displayName: String? = null,
    var email: String? = null,
    var photoUrl : String? = null,
    var userId: String? = null
)
```