# Firestore "No properties to serialize found on" in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

I am getting this Exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class
> java.lang.Void

on this line:

```
val glist = input.toObject(Glist::class.java)
```

I am **not** using proguard and the strange thing everything worked until implemented authentication.

I checked several answers but they include proguard or Java class models asking for public constructors which i think i already implement. I also tried implementing the `Serializable` which did not change anything.

```
data class Glist (
    var id: String,
    val ti: String,
    val cat: Int
) {
    constructor() : this("", "", 0)

    var lactuid = Fire.getUid()
    var lact = ActionHelper.CREATED_LIST
    var lacti = ""
    var arch = null
    var del = null
    var lactd: Date
    var cre: Date
    var cha: Date
    var own = Fire.getUid()
    var adminuid = null
    var col = ArrayList<String>(  )
    var ni = ArrayList<String>(  )
    var nci = ArrayList<String>(  )

    init {
        val now: Date = TimeUtil.getTime()
        lactd = now
        cre = now
        cha = now
        col.add(Fire.getUid())
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Kotlin firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911506/android-kotlin-firebase-database-databaseexception-no-properties-to-serialize-f)

Comment: As noted, i did not use proguard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was since some of the variables of the kotlin `data class` initialized as `null` but without any specific data type. I just added the data types and issue solved

```
data class Glist  (
    var id: String,
    val ti: String,
    val cat: Int
) {

    constructor() : this("", "", 0)

    var lactuid = Fire.getUid()
    var lact = ActionHelper.CREATED_LIST
    var lacti = ""
    var arch: Date? = null
    var del: Date? = null
    var lactd: Date
    var cre: Date
    var cha: Date
    var own = Fire.getUid()
    var adminuid: ArrayList<String>? = null
    var col = ArrayList<String>(  )
    var ni = ArrayList<String>(  )
    var nci = ArrayList<String>(  )

    init {
        val now: Date = TimeUtil.getTime()
        lactd = now
        cre = now
        cha = now
        col.add(Fire.getUid())
    }
}
```